# Regex Issues - Trying to turn general number into currency

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I have problem using `match(/.{1,3}/gi)` or `match(\/d{1,3}/g)` to split a string into 3 digits array each.

```
if(me.iselement(finppnr.inpprice)) {
    finppnr.inpprice.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
        let raw, ret;
        raw = finppnr.inpprice.value.split(".");
        raw = raw.join("").toString();
        if(raw.length > 0) {
            ret = raw.split("").reverse().join("").match(/.{1,3}/gi);
            ret = ret.join(".").split("").reverse().join("");
        }
        finppnr.inpprice.value = ret;
    });
}
```

here the HTML.

```
<div class="formcol">
    <div class="label">Item Price</div>
    <div class="field">
        <input class="inpprice finp" type="number">
    </div>
</div>
```

everything that i input into `finppnr.inpprice` larger then `1.000.000` will return an warning like this

> The specified value "1.231.231" is not a valid number. The value must match to the following regular expression: -?(\d+|\d+.\d+|.\d+)([eE][-+]?\d+)?

And the `finppnr.inpprice.value` suddenly became `''` (empty). Meanwhile using the string straight, doesn't return any warning or error.

```
ret = "52990000".split("").reverse().join("").match(/.{1,3}/gi);
ret = ret.join(".").split("").reverse().join("");
```

I newer at this regular expression and just don't yet understand how actually the regular expression work. Please help

Comment: Pls show the html ?

Comment: @Irvan Please explain exactly what you expect from the regex, by giving some examples of input/output.

Comment: @ariel i just edited the question to add the HTML. @Benny while this script `"52990000".split("").reverse().join("").match(/.{1,3}/gi)` work well, and return `'52.990.000'` (which as i expected), but when `"52990000"` changed/replaced by the value of '`inppnr.inpprice`' it return an warning and the value suddenly become empty.

Comment: "it return an warning and the value suddenly become empty" when i try to input number larger than 1.000.000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is not with the regex, it's that you are using a `number` input and giving it a value like `52.990.000`, *which is not a valid number at all*!

Number inputs are not able to interpret grouping separators, such as `,` or `.`, so numbers like `52,990,000`, `52,990.999`, etc. are all invalid and the input will not be able to interpret and thus render them.

A number like 999.999, on the other hand, *is* valid, since the `.` here simply acts as a decimal point.

All in all, your regex is fine, you have a problem with using a number input.

One quick solution would be to switch to a `type="text"` input, it can display arbitrary symbols.

If you are determined on keeping the `type="number"` input, you will have to find another solution, which will probably include positioning a `type="text"` input on top of your `type="number"` input, so that it is able to display the value the way you expect it to.